# Getting environment variables from Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, environment-variables, apache-cordova

i have some questions about using Apache Cordova.
As you see the title, is it possible to get environment variables from Cordova?
I searched on google almost half-a-day, but still i cannot found. Also i looked up for Cordova Plugin Registry, but either not found.

What i want to do is setting some kind of environment variable to "production" or "development" like NODE_ENV in Node.js.
It will be very appreciated that anyone give me a hand ;)

Comment: I need more information for helping you. Can you give a usage example? For what exactly do you need this?

Comment: Thanks, Sithys. I can't give you a example but i can tell you more detail. Before it, I made another way that separate options into JSON file and load them. I think it is fine, but my boss don't like it, and he want that set the environment variables from development environment(like nodejs in linux, $ export NODE_ENV=production), then receive those environment variables from JavaScript. Shorter, he wants to read environment variables from operating system and decision mode of the app that it is production or not. I hope you understand because i know my english is bad ;(

Comment: Is this helpful? http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/08/23/managing-environment-variables-for-your-ionic-application/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cordova hooks to check an environment variable (i.e. `NODE_ENV`)  and then configure your app appropriately. Example here: http://www.kdmooreconsulting.com/blogs/build-a-cordova-hook-to-setup-environment-specific-constants/